# What is the difference between $routes->get and $routes->add in codeigniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, backend, codeigniter-4

```
$routes->get('login', 'C_auth::display_login');
$routes->add('login', 'C_auth::display_login');
```

What is the difference between `get` and `add`? I test them both and it seems like they do the same thing

Comment: After reading the docs, the only difference I see is that `get` route will only be applied to `GET` requests(Try giving the same `URL` to a form for `POST` request); `get(), post(), put(), delete()` are particularly useful in `RESTFUL` applications whereas `add()` will work regardless of the request type. If there is no `POST` request `add()` and `get()` will work the same way and can be used interchangeably. Again, this is what I understand after reading the docs. You should verify by creating a demo and then posting an answer to help all the future users. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off i would like to thank @sauhardnc to set me on the right direction.

Yes, what @sauhardnc is correct, i tried routing a form with a `post` method to a route with `get` method and it gives an error. So if you have a form with a `post` method, use the `post` method in your route. `Add` would also work, but i think the method from your form and your route should be the same.

**This would be your route**

`$routes->post('register-user','C_auth::authenticate_registration');`

or

`$routes->add('register-user','C_auth::authenticate_registration');`

**This would be your form**

`<form action = '<?php echo route_to('register-user') ?>' method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`